`pnpm audit` shows a vulnerability; `pnpm why` doesn't list it
I'm trying to resolve a security vulnerability Node packages.  The vulnerability is reported by both pnpm and Dependabot.  The package manager is pnpm on this repo.
pnpm audit shows:
┌─────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ high                │ path-to-regexp outputs backtracking regular            │
│                     │ expressions                                            │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package             │ path-to-regexp                                         │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Vulnerable versions │ >=2.0.0 <3.3.0                                         │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched versions    │ >=3.3.0                                                │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Paths               │ . > *redacted* > *redacted* >                          │
│                     │ @nestjs/platform-fastify@10.3.9 > path-to-regexp@3.2.0 │
│                     │                                                        │
│                     │ . > *redacted* >                                       │
│                     │ @nestjs/platform-fastify@10.3.9 > path-to-regexp@3.2.0 │
│                     │                                                        │
│                     │ . > path-to-regexp@3.2.0                               │
├─────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info           │ https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9wv6-86v2-598j      │
└─────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

pnpm why path-to-regexp --depth=10 shows
❯ p why path-to-regexp --depth=10
Legend: production dependency, optional only, dev only

*redacted*

dependencies:
*redacted*
├─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
│ ├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express 10.4.12 peer
│ │ └─┬ express 4.21.1
│ │   └── path-to-regexp 0.1.10
│ └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0
├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express 10.4.12 peer
│ ├─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
│ │ └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0
│ └─┬ express 4.21.1
│   └── path-to-regexp 0.1.10
├─┬ @nestjs/testing 10.4.12 peer
│ ├─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
│ │ └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0
│ └─┬ @nestjs/platform-express 10.4.12 peer
│   └─┬ express 4.21.1
│     └── path-to-regexp 0.1.10
└─┬ nestjs-console 9.0.0 peer
  └─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
    └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0
*redacted*
└─┬ *redacted* peer
  └─┬ @nestjs/swagger 8.0.7 peer
    ├─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
    │ ├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express 10.4.12 peer
    │ │ └─┬ express 4.21.1
    │ │   └── path-to-regexp 0.1.10
    │ └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0
    └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0

devDependencies:
@nestjs/testing 10.4.12
├─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
│ ├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express 10.4.12 peer
│ │ └─┬ express 4.21.1
│ │   └── path-to-regexp 0.1.10
│ └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0
└─┬ @nestjs/platform-express 10.4.12 peer
  ├─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
  │ └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0
  └─┬ express 4.21.1
    └── path-to-regexp 0.1.10
nestjs-console 9.0.0
└─┬ @nestjs/core 10.4.12 peer
  ├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express 10.4.12 peer
  │ └─┬ express 4.21.1
  │   └── path-to-regexp 0.1.10
  └── path-to-regexp 3.3.0

Nowhere does pnpm why show path-to-regexp@3.2.0, so it's unclear to me where the vulnerable dependency is coming from. Dependabot and pnpm audit both flag the same vulnerability.
What am I missing?  Thanks.

Interestingly this is in pnpm.lock:
  '@nestjs/platform-fastify@10.3.9(@nestjs/common@10.4.12(class-transformer@0.5.1)(class-validator@0.14.1)(reflect-metadata@0.2.2)(rxjs@7.8.1))(@nestjs/core@10.4.12)':
    dependencies:
      '@fastify/cors': 9.0.1
      '@fastify/formbody': 7.4.0
      '@fastify/middie': 8.3.1
      '@nestjs/common': 10.4.12(class-transformer@0.5.1)(class-validator@0.14.1)(reflect-metadata@0.2.2)(rxjs@7.8.1)
      '@nestjs/core': 10.4.12(@nestjs/common@10.4.12(class-transformer@0.5.1)(class-validator@0.14.1)(reflect-metadata@0.2.2)(rxjs@7.8.1))(@nestjs/platform-express@10.4.12)(reflect-metadata@0.2.2)(rxjs@7.8.1)
      fastify: 4.27.0
      light-my-request: 5.13.0
      path-to-regexp: 3.2.0
      tslib: 2.6.2

but I'm not sure why.

Lock file is what matters, not "why" output. See https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/6995 , could be this issue

As Estus Flask mentioned, the resolved dependency in the pnpm.lock file was the culprit.  Overriding the dependency resolves the vulnerability.  In package.json:
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "path-to-regexp@>=3.2.0 <3.3.0": "^3.3.0"
    }
  },

This means "for each transitive dependency path-to-regexp between 3.2.0 inclusive and 3.3.0 exclusive, use path-to-regexp version 3.3.0 or higher, up to but not including 4.0.0".  This means that vulnerable packages are patched, but higher versions are ignored.

This is not an answer to the original question, but it was a solution to the underlying issue.
